# Word: Why empty space that splits consecutive rows in Table?

Tags: microsoft-word

Please see the 3 questions in the screenshot beneath.

[image]

**Edit of 2018 May 15:** [Para. 2](https://superuser.com/a/1289430/269574) solved this. 'Keep with Next' (Para. 1) was never selected:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your paragraph styles - looks like your red text includes "keep with next".
The black square in the 'Specify height" table means that some rows have a height specified, and some don't. I believe (based on your image) that a height has been set for the second row (the one with the red text). 
Click on the box with the black square to remove the setting (you may have to click twice if a tick comes up first time).

You may be using a table for a particular reason, but you can also set styles where there is a border around the paragraphs. Have a little experiment with these so see how they work.